# Python fill column based on values in other column (EXCEL INDEX MATCH FOR ROW AND COLUMN LOOKUP)

Tags: python, pandas, index-match

I would like to fill a new column in a dataframe1 by looking up the values in dataframe2, however the lookup is based on the values in the column of dataframe1.

for example the two columns in dataframe1 that determine the lookup in dataframe2 are:

| Lookup | security_type |
| --- | --- |
| Country!not_in_list | Equity |
| Country!empty | FX Forward |

columns of dataframe2:

| Lookup | Equity | FX Forward |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Country!not_in_list | 0,561686374 | 0,194140542 |
| Country!empty | 0,743154272 | 0,684586895 |

dataframe1 should have a new column called Score with the values looked up in dataframe 2:

| Lookup | security_type | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Country!not_in_list | Equity | 0,561686374 |
| Country!empty | FX Forward | 0,684586895 |

current code:

```
n=0
for i in dataframe1["Lookup"]:
    dataframe1["Score"]=""
    dataframe1.loc[n, "Score"] = dataframe2.loc[dataframe1["Lookup"][n], 
    [dataframe1["security_type"][n]]].values
    n += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
out = df1.merge(df2.melt(id_vars='Lookup',
                         var_name='security_type', value_name='Score'),
                on=['Lookup', 'security_type']
                )
```

output:

```
                Lookup security_type        Score
0  Country!not_in_list        Equity  0,561686374
1        Country!empty    FX Forward  0,684586895
```